# Redis cache spring boot with multy region

Tags: java, caching, redis, openshift

I would like to ask one question. I have 2 regions on open shift b01 and b02. I have Java microservice which located in both region with different instances . If I will use redis cache ,will I have the same cache  in both instance or will have own cache for micro in each region ?

Comment: read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)